# Split Interval to equal Parts, adding up

Tags: python

I need to split an Interval, for example 1-16, to smaller intervalls like n=4. For 16 this would be 1..4, 5..8, 9..12, 13..16.
I have this code from another question here:

```
def interval(l, n):
w = (l[1] - l[0]) // n
return [[l[0]+i*w, l[0]+(i+1)*w] for i in range(n)]
```

This just returns [[1, 4], [4, 7], [7, 10], [10, 13]], how can i modify this code?

Comment: The [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) library is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: That looks interesting @0x5453, never knew such existed !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for anyone after me:
none of above worked, but i mixed the answers:

```
def interval(n, t):
ret = []
for i in range(t):
        ret.append([(int)(i*(n-1)/t+1), (int)((i+1)*(n-1)/t)])
        
return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

To split up a list into n equal chunks, this method will suffice:

```
def interval(l, n):
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        ret.append(l[i:i+n])
    return ret
```

Worth noting that in python, whitespace/indentation DOES matter, so the method you posted in your question would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the list slicing method. This will help :

```
def interval(l, n):
    t = []
    lnth = len(l)
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):     
        t.append(l[i:i+n])
    return t
```

Note that `l[i:i+n]` do not need to check if the value `i+n` is less than that of the length of the list.